# An example showing $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

It cannot be a UFD because it's the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ and has class number 3. How can we give an example showing this?

Comment: Probably you want to use the identity $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$ to get a second factorisation of an integer.

Comment: @preferred_anon thanks! I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take $\mathfrak{p}$ a non-principal inversible prime ideal.
- Take $a\in \mathfrak{p},\not \in \mathfrak{p}^2$  (this can be done in the finite ring $O_K/(p^2)$ where $p=char(O_K/\mathfrak{p})$)
- Let $m$ be the order of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the class group, so $\mathfrak{p}^m=(b)$.
- $b$ is irreducible but $(b)$ is not a prime ideal.
- $a^m \in (b)$
- Neither $a$ nor $a^{m-1}$ is in $(b)$ so $a^m$ has more than one factorization.

Comment: Hi,  reuns. Essay question: is there a way to express the class number 3  as ternary cubic (integer)  polynomials, alternative to the "principal"  $  x^3 +7 y^3 + 49 z^3  - 21 xyz  \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: Dear prof, would you rephrase the question? Magma says $(2,1+\sqrt[3]{7})$ is non-principal of norm $2$ and generates the classgroup @WillJagy

Comment: Having class number 3 (for a cubic field) has meaining in term of class field theory but it seems complicated. Here the Hilbert class field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7},\cos(2\pi/7))$

Comment: Thanks. I asked related things, years ago.

Comment: I had not noticed the $(2, 1 + \sqrt[3] 7)$   comment. I will fiddle with that, see what might be available for translating that into a ternary cubic.